# Using BSON type provider in F# Script

Tags: mongodb, f#, bson, f#-data

I'm trying to use the `Bson` type provider to do some work with a `MongoDB` database. in an `F#` script.

I've taken the following steps.

1. I've created the `Bson` files by using:-

   ```
   mongodump /host:starbug /db:Logger /out:data
   ```
2. I've built the type provider from the source from https://github.com/visemet/FSharp.Data.Bson
3. I've created the following F# script file:

   ```
   #I "../../FSharp.Data.Bson/bin" // Location of Dll's created by step 1.  

   #r "FSharp.Data.Bson.Runtime.dll"
   #r "FSharp.Data.Bson.dll"
   #r "MongoDB.Bson.dll"

   open BsonProvider

   type AccessLogs = BsonProvider<"./data/EkmLogger/access_logs.bson">
   type SQLiteLogs = BsonProvider<"./data/EkmLogger/sqlite_logs.bson">

   let accessLogs = AccessLogs.GetSamples().[0]
   ```

But the last line is showing the following error in VS 2013

```
    The type provider 'BsonProvider.ProviderImplementation.BsonProvider' reported an error in the context of provided type 'BsonProvider.BsonProvider,Path="./data/Logger/access_logs.bson"', member 'GetSamples'. 
    The error: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Data.Bson.Runtime, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
    The system cannot find the file specified. C:\Development\fsharp-scripts\Logger\AccessSqliteStats.fsx
```

Any idea what's wrong?